# json response callback load store extjs

Tags: json, extjs, callback, store

I have a JSON store that load data from a PHP script. This script call a Web Service and sometimes it get some errors and I need to capture them and show them in my app.
In my script I print this line when I get an error:

```
echo '{"success": "false", "error": "'.$res->state->Description.'"}';
```

In my app I have this code to load the store

```
targheStore.load({
                            params: { targa: searchForm.getValues().targa },
                            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                                Ext.getBody().dom.style.cursor = "default";
                                if(!success){
                                    $("#message2").slideDown('fast');
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $("#message2").slideUp('medium')
                                    }, 2700);
                                }
                            }

                        });
```

The jQuery code is to show a message "No record found" from the top, but I want to show the error message that I receive from json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the operation argument is a request and response object. Use the response object as you would any Ajax response should allow you to handle your messages the way you'd like.

I suggest declaring a globally available handler for processing operation to look for JSON.parse(response.responseText).hasOwnProperty("error") and doing your custom operation in that way.

If you're not using JSONP for communication you can stuff your message in the raw text returned from an HTTP error code (400+) and the {error:} handler in your ajax would be the best way to route errors.

Comment: YOu should NOT use the "error" property, instead use the "msg" property. ExtJS uses the error property for record validation errors.

Comment: I advised him to look INSIDE the responseText for an error property - as that is what he defined in his PHP emitter. Not the root response itself.

Comment: I know, still he should change both the js part and the php part to use the "msg" property instead. Then he would go along the Ext conventions. Create and update requests by default put the list of validation errors inside the "error" property.

Comment: @RolandSchütz I've updated my response to include your points with enough general detail for implementation. Would appreciate a vote yea/nay. Thanks!